# Azure FunctionApp timers quit firing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a few Functions within an Azure FunctionApp. All of the functions are set to trigger every 5 minutes, and have been working fine for the past 9 months. About 2 weeks ago they stopped firing. There has been 1 or 2 instances of each Function that have executed since then.

I can manually execute the function with inconsistent success. Sometimes it will execute, sometimes it won't. I am basing this execution rate on the data in the Monitoring tab. The function app is using the Consumption service plan.

I have not been able to find any errors in the logs or anything else of value. What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

[image]

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Do you mean that even when you manually run it from Portal, it works inconsistently? What happens when it doesn't? Do you get an error? Or no output at all?

Comment: Also, can you share your function app name (that's the **app** name, not function name!), either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'sometimes it won't' , what do you exactly mean? Manual execution triggers the function which later on fails or does it not trigger it all? Have you considered turning on Application Insights for your Function app? 

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/

Comment: I mean that I get no output at all. I press "Run" , and I see a red "Cancel" box flash at the top, and then nothing in the output window. When I go to the monitor tab. It may show that it executed, and it may not.

Comment: I have hooked up Application Insights, but it basically shows the same activity as I see in the monitor tab. My app name is "K360Functions"

Comment: @DavidEbbo any thoughts on what might be happening here? The function did run once a few hours ago, but for something that should run every 5 minutes that is not very good.

Comment: @philpastor I'll try to take a look later today

Comment: @philpastor Can you give a specific UTC timestamp where the functions were not invoked? I looked at 2017-09-08 17:00:00 UTC, and all 5 functions got invoked. I tried a few other timeframes with same results.

Comment: @DavidEbbo thanks for looking into this. Where do you see those results? In my Invocation log the most recent is 6 hours ago...

Comment: @philpastor I'm looking in our internal logs. My guess is that your functions are getting executed, but the logging is not working. Are you using the Monitor tab, or have you enabled App Insights? App Insights is recommended.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes, I have enabled app insights, but it is only slightly better. It shows 5 server requests in the past 24 hours, and one of them was an exception ("script compilation error").

Comment: for whatever reason it has now been running properly for the past 2 hours.

Comment: If you again see a case where it's not running, please share the UTC timeframe so we can look it up.